# kernel panic when trying to play audio

Tags: audio, kernel-panic

I'm trying to get my TAS2505 audio chip working with my arm64 linux system (IMX8MM).

It gets detected as an audio device however when I try to play any kind of audio I get a kernel panic.

dmesg:

```
[    0.594275] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'reset-gpios' property of node '/soc@0/bus@30800000/i2c@30a50000/tlv320aic32x4-hifi@18[0]' - status (0)
[    0.594333] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up ldoin-supply from device tree
[    0.594343] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up ldoin-supply property in node /soc@0/bus@30800000/i2c@30a50000/tlv320aic32x4-hifi@18 failed
[    0.594380] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up iov-supply from device tree
[    0.594501] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up dv-supply from device tree
[    0.594613] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up av-supply from device tree
[    1.163560] ALSA device list:
[    1.163567]   #0: tas2505-hifi
```

aplay -vv /home/test.wav

```
Playing WAVE '/home/test.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
Plug PCM: Hardware PCM card 0 'tas2505-hifi' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 24000
  period_size  : 6000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 6000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 24000
  stop_threshold   : 24000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 6755399441055744000
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
####################################  +            | 75%
```

debug console gives this:

```
[  122.210201] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 0000000000000000
[  122.218990] Mem abort info:
[  122.221782]   ESR = 0x96000044
[  122.224835]   EC = 0x25: DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[  122.230147]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[  122.233200]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[  122.236340]   FSC = 0x04: level 0 translation fault
[  122.241216] Data abort info:
[  122.244094]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000044
[  122.247928]   CM = 0, WnR = 1
[  122.250894] user pgtable: 4k pages, 48-bit VAs, pgdp=00000000465c8000
[  122.257336] [0000000000000000] pgd=0000000000000000, p4d=0000000000000000
[  122.264130] Internal error: Oops: 96000044 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[  122.269703] Modules linked in:
[  122.272759] CPU: 0 PID: 2065 Comm: aplay Not tainted 5.15.32-karo+gc01cf92b4155 #1
[  122.280331] Hardware name: Ka-Ro TX8M-1610 module on GOcontroll Moduline Screen for av123z7m-n17 screen (DT)
[  122.290157] pstate: 800000c5 (Nzcv daIF -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[  122.297121] pc : sdma_transfer_init+0x1e8/0x330
[  122.301661] lr : sdma_transfer_init+0x19c/0x330
[  122.306194] sp : ffff8000097b39c0
[  122.309507] x29: ffff8000097b39c0 x28: ffff000002e68298 x27: ffff000002e6c6b0
[  122.316649] x26: 00000000000000c0 x25: 0000000000000000 x24: 00000000000003c2
[  122.323791] x23: 0000000000000020 x22: ffff800009355200 x21: ffff000002e68080
[  122.330933] x20: ffff000006243500 x19: ffff000002e68298 x18: ffffffffffffffff
[  122.338075] x17: 203a6c656e6e6168 x16: 632063696c637963 x15: ffff8000092a12ec
[  122.345218] x14: 0000000000000000 x13: 000000000000068c x12: ffff8000097b35e0
[  122.352359] x11: ffff8000091c19e0 x10: 00000000fffff000 x9 : 0000000000000000
[  122.359501] x8 : ffff800009355280 x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : 000000000000003f
[  122.366642] x5 : 0000000000000040 x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : 0000000000000004
[  122.373783] x2 : 0000000000000000 x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : 0000000001830020
[  122.380926] Call trace:
[  122.383371]  sdma_transfer_init+0x1e8/0x330
[  122.387557]  sdma_prep_dma_cyclic+0xc4/0x3f0
[  122.391830]  snd_dmaengine_pcm_trigger+0xec/0x1c0
[  122.396540]  dmaengine_pcm_trigger+0x18/0x24
[  122.400814]  snd_soc_pcm_component_trigger+0x164/0x230
[  122.405957]  soc_pcm_trigger+0xbc/0x1c0
[  122.409796]  snd_pcm_do_start+0x38/0x44
[  122.413637]  snd_pcm_action_single+0x48/0xa4
[  122.417910]  snd_pcm_action+0x7c/0x9c
[  122.421573]  snd_pcm_start+0x24/0x30
[  122.425150]  __snd_pcm_lib_xfer+0x718/0x800
[  122.429335]  snd_pcm_common_ioctl+0x1508/0x1a7c
[  122.433867]  snd_pcm_ioctl+0x34/0x50
[  122.437444]  __arm64_sys_ioctl+0xb8/0xe0
[  122.441369]  invoke_syscall+0x48/0x114
[  122.445123]  el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x44/0xfc
[  122.449829]  do_el0_svc+0x28/0x90
[  122.453146]  el0_svc+0x28/0x80
[  122.456205]  el0t_64_sync_handler+0xa4/0x130
[  122.460478]  el0t_64_sync+0x1a0/0x1a4
[  122.464147] Code: b90026c0 52800400 531b6af7 72a03060 (b9000320) 
[  122.470241] ---[ end trace 34c93087276a38a7 ]---
[  122.474858] Kernel panic - not syncing: Oops: Fatal exception
[  122.480603] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[  122.484527] Kernel Offset: disabled
[  122.488013] CPU features: 0x00002001,20000842
[  122.492369] Memory Limit: none
```

I'm kinda lost on how I should continue on this.

Comment: Try kernel 6.0.2. If it still panics file a bug report.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not in a position to update the kernel, I'm dependent on the kernel NXP provides for their IMX processors, and the dependent on the kernel of KA-RO electronics who makes the COM module i use.

Comment: Ask your vendor then. Kernel developers or the community are very unlikely to help. A fix will most likely require a patch which means kernel recompilation.

Comment: recompiling the kernel and applying patches is not an issue, that's been a regular occurance trying to get everything working. I've had to apply multiple patches already to get my display working as intended and to add a newer RTC driver.

Comment: Hm, why don't you compile and test 6.0.2 then? ;-)

Comment: Well I might be wrong on this but I think I rely on changes NXP makes to the kernel to get it working on the IMX8MM, and they are quite far from being up to date unfortunately

Comment: Then at the very least try to compile the latest 5.15.74 kernel with the necessary patches. 43 extra point releases are nothing to sneeze at. Could contain some audio fixes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were multiple issues, but only one causing the panic.

I was missing an IMX SDMA driver that needs to be included in the rootfs. So I had to bitbake a reference yocto build, mount the rootfs, rip out the driver from  /lib/firmware/imx/sdma, and put it in my custom rootfs.

After putting that in the kernel panic went away, audio still wasn't working. But this was due to faults in my devicetree which were impossible to troubleshoot with the kernel panicking constantly.